# How can I counteract offensive comments?

Tags: support, comment, flagging

I have unfortunately gotten into a shouting match with another MSE user on the question referenced below.  I would like to flag the user's latest (slanderous) comment to my answer but I see no option to do so.  Maybe I have not enough reputation?  What then can I do?  No, I am not interested in retaliatory diwnvotes which cost me reputation and do not really solve the problem.

[Is the catenary the trajectory of anything?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1731382/is-the-catenary-the-trajectory-of-anything/1731391?noredirect=1#comment3537260_1731391)

Comment: The flag icon is to the left of the comment below the upvote triangle. And don't respond to such comments with insults....

Comment: I removed my comment, but do not see the flag icon.  What now?

Comment: Do you see an option to upvote the comment?

Comment: Can you upvote comments? (You need to hover to the left of the comment then the icons will appear.)

Comment: Just an option, I typically delete whatever I have done on a question when things get that bad. Points don't really get you anything; meanwhile, if I leave something there or fight back, I am angry for days perhaps, if i delete I am over it in hours.

Comment: I thought about that but I have +106 net reputation on the question.  Maybe living well is the best revenge?

Comment: Oscar, sure, if you cannot stand to delete it then move on; the idea of letting the other guy have the last word is useful. I found that I would sometimes mistakenly answer a question by someone with whom I had had genuine problems in the past. Difficult to keep track of all the people to avoid on the site itself, so I have a file on my home computer called idiots.txt. It has the MSE id lines from their profile pages. I update it when some idiot changes username. Usually I put the question number of one that shows why I do not want to interact with that person again.

Comment: "Flag a comment by clicking on the flag icon that appears when you hover the mouse over the comment." [How does comment voting and flagging work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17364/how-does-comment-voting-and-flagging-work)

Comment: @WillJagy I decided ipon that course of action, largely because I can't seem to reach the Flag icon from my cell phone, hovering does not appear to work on that platform.  Uh ... You won't see me answering any more of that user's questions in the future.

Comment: As a workaround you can also flag the post "other" and explain the situation. (For the specific case I flagged that comment by now. I suspect it will dissapear soonish.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Comments are ephemeral. Don't let a misguided comment get you down. If a negative comment is valid, you might improve your answer in response. If a negative comment is invalid, either ignore it or explain calmly why it is not true. Don't fuel a flame war.

If a comment is rude or offensive, [flag it as such](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts).